# Return results if value is contained in ELK String

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm attempting to search for documents that contain a value on elk, the value is separate by | symbol. For example, within an ELK document there exists the key:value -> `elk_value : 'AGA>23/180@20210212-1|AGA>23/180@20210212-2|AGA>23/180@20210212-3'` How to search all documents that contain `AGA>23/180@20210212-1` for field `elk_value` ?

I've tried term:

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "elk_value.keyword": "AGA>23/180@20210212-1"
    }
  }
}
```

But 0 records are found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to use a [pattern tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-tokenizer.html), which will split the text into tokens when `|` is encountered.**

Adding a working example

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "pattern",
          "pattern": "\\|| "
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "elk_value": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Analyze API:**

```
GET /_analyze

{
  "analyzer" : "my_analyzer",
  "text" : "'AGA>23/180@20210212-1|AGA>23/180@20210212-2|AGA>23/180@20210212-3"
}
```

Following tokens will be generated

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "'AGA>23/180@20210212-1",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 22,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "AGA>23/180@20210212-2",
      "start_offset": 23,
      "end_offset": 44,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "AGA>23/180@20210212-3",
      "start_offset": 45,
      "end_offset": 66,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "elk_value": "AGA>23/180@20210212-6|AGA>23/180@20210212-4|AGA>23/180@20210212-5"
}
{
  "elk_value": "AGA>23/180@20210212-1|AGA>23/180@20210212-4|AGA>23/180@20210212-5"
}
{
  "elk_value": "AGA>23/180@20210212-1|AGA>23/180@20210212-2|AGA>23/180@20210212-3"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "elk_value": "AGA>23/180@20210212-1"
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "66320921",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.4700036,
        "_source": {
          "elk_value": "AGA>23/180@20210212-1|AGA>23/180@20210212-2|AGA>23/180@20210212-3"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "66320921",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.4700036,
        "_source": {
          "elk_value": "AGA>23/180@20210212-1|AGA>23/180@20210212-4|AGA>23/180@20210212-5"
        }
      }
    ]
```